# Alternative method of creating Vector2

Tags: godot-4, godot-3

Having to re-learn stuff after upgrading to Godot 4.x. I can declare an int with

```
@export var spoon:int = 224 # or 
@export var spoon:= 224
```

However, I can't seem to use the same for a vector 2:
@export var variablename: type = value

```
@export var canvas_size:= Vector2(224, 256)  # works
@export var canvas_size:Vector2 = (224, 256) # doesn't work
```

Results in Error: expected closing ")" after grouping expression

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, this does not work

I can do little more than reiterating what you discovered. This does not work:

```
@export var canvas_size:Vector2 = (224, 256) # doesn't work
```

You would have to write this:

```
@export var canvas_size:Vector2 = Vector2(224, 256)
```

But why when you can write this:

```
@export var canvas_size := Vector2(224, 256)
```

I want to point out that the proposed syntax is not really equivalent to the `int` literal, given that the `Vector2` type (despite being built-in and value type) is not primitive, but composite. So it seems to be closer to `Array` (`[]`) and `Dictionary` [`{}`] initializers.

---

### Why this does not work

Why does that syntax not work? Because nobody implemented it. Features start up not existing, and somebody has to program them.

Currently the parser only uses what precedes the open parenthesis to decide how to interpret the expression... But, for this syntax, deciding how to interpret the parenthesis would have to be delayed until it knows if there is a comma or not...

Furthermore, how many commas, given that the type would depend on the number of elements if it will support `Vector3` and `Vector4`.

On the same order of ideas, the integer vectors (`Vector2i`, `Vector3i` and `Vector4i`) throw another wrench on this. For example, since in `(224, 256)` all the elements are `int`s, I would expect a `Vector2i` instead of a `Vector2` (which uses `float`s).

I'm not saying it can't be done, it can be done. I'm postulating that it might not be worth it (a lot of effort for little gain). But don't take me as gatekeeper...

You can [write a proposal](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/new/choose) if you really care about this feature, make your case.

---

### No, this is not new in Godot 4

By the way, I'll point out that barring `@export` it is the same situation in Godot 3, it would be like this:

```
export var spoon:int = 224 # works
export var spoon:= 224 # works
export var canvas_size:= Vector2(224, 256)  # works
export var canvas_size:Vector2 = (224, 256) # doesn't work
```

*Yes, Godot 3 had typed variables.*